# CSS Child Descendants

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I just saw this question that is answered correctly here on Stack.

The question was how to select the first two li after each .class1 element.

```
<ul>
  <li>Something</li>
  <li class="class1">Important</li>
  <li>I want this</li>
  <li>I want this</li>
  <li class="class1">Important</li>
  <li>I want this</li>
  <li>I want this</li>
  <li>Something</li>
  <li>Something</li>
</ul>
```

This was the (great) correct and accepted answer:

```
.class1 + li will select the first subsequent sibling.
.class1 + * + li will select the second.
```

to keep specificity low, you could also use:

```
.class1 + *,
.class1 + * + * {...}
```

Now, I was playing around with this and was wondering why this doesn't work:

```
li.class1 li:nth-child(-n+2) {color:red;}
```

But works this way:

```
li:nth-child(-n+2) {color:red;}
```

Comment: replacing the space with a plus sign would work ;)

Comment: Actually, I tried that already and it didn't work. I guess + sign selects the first adjacent element so nth- doesn't work in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because when you use

```
li.class1 li:nth-child(-n+2) {color:red;}
```

you are catching that li element and you are looking for his child but li elements here doesn't have any child so it won't work. If ul would have class 'class1' maybe it would work like you want.

Comment: I tried this with +, but it seems like -nth doesn't work with + in CSS.

Comment: I just did edisoni.1337. I gave it up-vote thinking I marked it as correct. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

`li.class1 li:nth-child(-n+2) {color:red;}`

This giving styles to an `li` inside an `li` having class `class1`

This will work if the HTML is like

```
<li class="class1">
  ......
  <li></li>
  ......
</li>
```